# Select element stuck to an input element HTML

Tags: html, forms

I want to make a select element stick to an input element in html, similar to the buttons with dropdowns from Bootstrap, except that I don't want an action to be performed, I just want to chose an option. 
The only way I can do this is by just positioning the input box next to the select element:

```
<select id="types" name = "Type" style="height: 26px;">
    <option value="Ta" selected="selected">Ta</option>
    <option value="Fa">Fa</option>
    <option value="Na">Na</option>
</select>


<input id="positions" style="position:absolute; top:200px; left:755px" type="text" id="txtSelectedType" name="SelectedType" value="" />
```

And it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: So what is the question? Also why position element absolutely? Different browsers will have different `select` default CSS applied

Comment: Not really sure what you are asking? Or what you are trying to do. Can you add a bit more explanation please

Comment: so do you need styling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@AlFra: Yes, it needed styling, what worked for me was something like this:

```
<div style="float:left;margin-left:10px;">
<label for="outref" style="color:white" id="label5">Out Ref</label>
  <select id="outref" name = "outref" style="height: 26px;color:black;font-weight: 500;">
              <option value="Fa" selected="selected" >Fa</option>
              <option value="Na" >Na</option>
              <option value="Ta" >Ta</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div style="float:left;">
          <label for="out" style="color:white">&nbsp;</label>
          <input type = "text" id = "out" name = "out"  style="overflow: hidden; width: 40px;">
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
input, label {
    display:block;
}
select, label {
    display:block;
}
```